# Extracting message from URL and display it HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this http://localhost/resume/Template/index.html?msg=Message%20Sent%20Successfully

how do I extract the message "Message Sent Successfully and display it in this form

```
<form action="send_form_email.php" name="contactForm" method="post">
    //I want to display the message here
    <h4>E-mail</h4>
    <div class="border-stripes">
        <input type="email" class="textfield" name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail address" />
    </div>
    <h4>Message</h4>
    <div class="border-stripes">
        <textarea class="textarea" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `urldecode` you can use. Please check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: You want this in `javascript` or `php`

Comment: tushar I don't mind any.

Answer (score 0):

This should echo the GET variable:

```
<?php echo urldecode($_GET['msg']); ?>
```

Comment: it still isn't showing the message in the form. note that I have the form saved as html file

Comment: OK well unless you have configured your web-server (Apache?) to serve html files as php files I think that is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it in php (note that there is no security check for XSS)

```
<form action="send_form_email.php" name = "contactForm" method="post">
                    <?php echo urldecode($_GET['msg']); ?>
                    <h4>E-mail</h4>
                    <div class="border-stripes"><input type="email" class="textfield" name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail address" /></div>
                    <h4>Message</h4>
                    <div class="border-stripes"><textarea class="textarea" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Your message"></textarea></div><br /><br />
                    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

else in js

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
var msg = getParameterByName('msg');
$( "form" ).prepend( "<p>"+msg+"</p>" );
```

The function `getParameterByName` is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: the one in php still doesn't display anything!! Note that the form is saved as html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in javascript then you can try to parse query string:

```
var query = (function() {
    function decode(string) {
        return decodeURIComponent(string.replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    var result = {};
    if (location.search) {
        location.search.substring(1).split('&').forEach(function(pair) {
            pair = pair.split('=');
            result[decode(pair[0])] = decode(pair[1]);
        });
    }
    return result;
})();

$('form[name=contactForm]').prepend('<p>' + query['msg'] + '</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

I have write down the function for same using that you can access any parameter of URL.

Example:

```
function getParamValue(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(location.href);
    if (results == null)
        return "";
    else
        return decodeURI(results[1]);
}

alert(getParamValue('param'));
```

Your solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/tb8cetLy/1/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are doing something like this in `send_form_email.php`

```
// process form data
// redirect to index.html with $_GET['msg'] variable
```

If you want **pretty URLs**, use a function like this below, include it on top of your common file

```
session_start();

function flash_set($k,$v)
{
    $_SESSION['flash'][$k] = $v;
}

function flash_get($k)
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['flash'][$k]))
    {
        $msg = $_SESSION['flash'][$k];
        unset($_SESSION['flash'][$k]);
        return $msg;
    }
    return '';
}
```

change the `send_form_email.php` to redirect without `$_GET` parameters, after you process your form put this,

```
// process form data
flash_set('form','Message Sent Successfully');
// redirect here
```

Now, use this in your form like,

```
<form action="send_form_email.php" name="contactForm" method="post">
<?php echo flash_get('form')?> // I want to display the message here
<h4>E-mail</h4>
```

The flash message will only show up single time after being redirected, if user refreshes the page, it disappears!!

Answer (score -1):

In HTML/PHP only, you would use `urldecode($_GET['msg'])`

You can also do it with javascript with a function like :

```
function getQuerystring(key, default_) {
    if (default_==null) default_=""; 
    key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)");
    var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if(qs == null)
        return default_;
    else
        return qs[1];
}
```

This function will allow you to get msg with `var msg = getQuerystring("msg");` and you can mix it with unescape functions ( http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp ).

Comment: Sorry, this is a function found on the web, using it in project but can't explain it